# How to update css for doughnut chart with ng2-charts

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I use *ng2-charts* and *chartjs* for angular9.
I draw a doughnut chart, and it will be shown line this:

[image]

But, I expected it will be like this:
The width of the line will smaller

[image]

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add the custom options to decrease the width of doughnut chart:

[image]

and all of the options is here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html

```
    public DonutChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
        options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 80
        }
   };
```